# C++ stringstream not working correctly after updated with stringstream::str()

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I know that `stringstream` can be updated with `stringstream::str()`, but if I input something else into the `stringstream` after that, it is not working as expected. The following snippet demonstrates the phenomenon:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    stringstream ss; //ostringstream gives the same output
    ss << "Original string ";
    ss.str("Updated string ");
    ss << "sth else";
    cout << ss.str() << endl;
}
```

I expect to get the output

```
Updated string sth else
```

But it actually outputs

```
sth elsestring
```

It seems that rather that appending the newly inputted string at the end of the current string (in my case `Updated string`), it tries to override it from the beginning. What is wrong with my code?

[Here's a live demo](http://ideone.com/hFRE6R)

Comment: When using stringstream you have to deal with input/output positions and states - just avoid it and use istingstream or ostingstream.

Comment: @DieterLücking Thanks for the suggestion. I tried with ostringstream, it gives the same output.

Comment: Also, do not reuse it - use a new instance, instead of manipulating the buffer with str(....)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add [`std::ios_base::app`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) to the `openmode`. It ensures that the `stringstream` object seeks to the end of the stream before every write. Try this:

```
stringstream ss(std::ios_base::app|std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::out);
```

Comment: @user2079303 The values are unspecified but the behaviour is specified in `27.5.3.1.4 [ios::openmode]`. Also, it works on [ideone](http://ideone.com/WIVW1k). I forked it from yours since your version was just passing in `ate`?

Comment: @Pradhan I did change that to `ios_base::app` from `ios_base::ate`, but indeed my mistake was to leave out `ios_base::out`. That said, `ios_base::ate` (with `ios_base::out`) should work as well, right? (well it does in ideone http://ideone.com/dJxnCk)

Comment: @user2079303 That's odd. I interpreted it to mean that the seek to end is only done at open and expected `ate` to fail [here](http://ideone.com/Z8zi50). But it doesn't. Both `app` and `ate` gave the same results.

Comment: according to both [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/str) and [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/) `ate` should be guaranteed to set the position to end on `str(s)` since c++11. But I can't find anything about that from the standard itself... About [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/) claims that other values than `in`,`out`,`ate` to `stringstream` c'tor is impl. defined, cppreference doesn't mention and I can't find anything from standard either so I suspect it's bs.

Comment: @user2079303 It is in the *postconditions* in `27.8.2.3 [stringbuf.members]`.

Comment: Well, I don't see mentions of other modes than `in` and `out` in the draft. Do you have the official standard? *Effects* states though `initializes the input and output sequences according to mode` which I suppose that counts as `immediately after opening` for the behaviour of `ate`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70729/discussion-between-pradhan-and-user2079303).